# Join query in Hanami-model

Tags: ruby, hanami, hanami-model

Is it possible to create join query in subclass of `Hanami::Repository`?

I found that [this](https://github.com/hanami/model/pull/228) pull request implements this feature but I can't find it in current codebase.

Comment: Hi, `Hanami-Model` is based on `rom-rb`. Take a look at its documentation to find out to make a join query http://rom-rb.org/learn/sql/joins/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hanami model based on rom, that's why you can use `Relation#join` method with a needful relation.

For this you need to call `join` method for one relation and set other relation as an attribute:

```
class PostRepository < Hanami::Repository
  associations do
    has_many :comments
  end

  # ...

  def join_example(date_range)
    posts    # => posts relation
    comments # => comments relation


    posts
      .join(comments) # set relation object here
      .where(comments[:created_at].qualified => date_range)
      .as(Post).to_a
  end
end
```

And that's all.

Some helpful links:

1. [rom-sql tests for `left_join`](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom-sql/blob/master/spec/unit/relation/left_join_spec.rb)
2. [A real example](https://github.com/davydovanton/hanami-contributors/blob/master/lib/contributors/repositories/contributor_repository.rb#L11-L19)

Comment: He can also do this as `aggregate(:comments).where(comments[:created_at].qualified => date_range).as(Post).to_a` since he has the one-to-many association defined.